# How I can show which doctor is available now?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am writing a doctor searching application where users can search which doctors are available right now beside other options. The table Doctors has few columns among which one column is **openinghours** (type:text) and here I store the total opening hours in a single entry for each row as follow:

```
Mo.
08:00-13:00
14:00-18:00

Tu.
14:00-20:00

We.
08:00-13:00
14:00-18:00

Th.
07:00-14:00

Fr.
08:00-13:00
14:00-18:00

Sa.
No

Su.
No
```

One advantage of storing data in the column **openinghours** in this way is, this is how I will exactly show the data to the user. In another column  **doctoravailable** (type boolean: yes/no), I want to show if the doctor is available now or not. Is it possible to write a function in MYSQL which will automatically update column **doctoravailable** by checking the column **openinghours** always? How can I achieve it? Is there any other better way to achieve the goal?

My plan:
I considered to create a view where column **doctoravailable** will be a function of **openinghours**. But I am not sure if this is the proper way or if any better way is available.

Comment: Any reason for negative vote without any explantation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. The question is how you'll update the table. You may have a cron job to update the table at specified times. One option is to update the table when a user does the search.

```
mysql> desc doctors;
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| weekdays  | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start     | time       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| end       | time       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| available | char(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> select * from doctors;
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| weekdays | start    | end      | available |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|        1 | 08:00:00 | 13:00:00 | n         |
|        1 | 14:00:00 | 18:00:00 | n         |
|        2 | 14:00:00 | 20:00:00 | n         |
|        3 | 08:00:00 | 13:00:00 | n         |
|        3 | 14:00:00 | 18:00:00 | n         |
|        4 | 07:00:00 | 14:00:00 | n         |
|        5 | 08:00:00 | 13:00:00 | n         |
|        5 | 14:00:00 | 18:00:00 | n         |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+

mysql> update doctors set available='y' where weekdays = weekday(now()) and start < time(now()) and end > time(now());

mysql> update doctors set available='n' where not (weekdays = weekday(now()) and start < time(now()) and end > time(now()));
```

Comment: Of course the real table has other columns and one of them is doctor names and you need to duplicate the rows in each time slot for each doctor.

Comment: Really good solution. Thanks a lot for your effort. I selected your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Storing **openinghours** as a single text column isn't a good idea, since it will require string manipulation and type conversion in your queries to calculate whether a doctor is available or not, and it'll prevent the DBMS from effectively indexing opening and closing times. Queries filtering for times between opening and closing hours (e.g. to get all available doctors) will be slower than necessary.

Instead, store opening and closing times as two separate `TIME` columns. Your application code can then format that information for display to the user.

A view for **doctoravailable** is a good idea and it's maintenance-free. Having to run a query once a minute to update each doctor's status sounds like a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will create the solution based on it. It helped.